# Unable to update input field values using Signals - React

Tags: reactjs, signals, preact

I am using @preact/signals-react for state management. I have 3 input fields and a common changeHandler function. I pass a unique name for each of those input fields and update the signal to get the final value. However, when I type in anything, I do not see any updates. Can someone help me please?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals-react";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const state = useSignal({
    textField1: "",
    textField2: "",
    textField3: ""
  });

  const onHandleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    (state.value as any)[name] = value;
  };

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <TextField
        name="textField1"
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onHandleChange}
        value={state.value.textField1}
      />
      <TextField
        name="textField2"
        id="filled-basic"
        label="Filled"
        variant="filled"
        onChange={onHandleChange}
        value={state.value.textField2}
      />
      <TextField
        name="textField3"
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Standard"
        variant="standard"
        onChange={onHandleChange}
        value={state.value.textField3}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is my stackblitz: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-knuth-vnrdkj?file=/demo.tsx:0-1261

Comment: For more context, if you wanted to keep same approach to update would need some sort of deeply reactive stores as mentioned https://github.com/preactjs/signals/issues/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the individual properties are not signals themselves, updating a property like that is basically mutating the value of the signal and not setting signal value. What you could do is

```
    state.value = { ...state, [name]: value };
```

which will set the value for the signal.

Alternatively you could have separate signals but I don't know how practical that is. Maybe an object of signals but I don't know if that works in preact. Don't see why not but worth checking.

Hope that helps

Comment: Doesnt work. https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-worker-tkgfqv?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: seems to work, can type and it updates.

Comment: Or it did. Guess these links update.. but this https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-snow-gt2zy2?file=/demo.tsx should work

Comment: Happens in a way that only if the input field is not focused, the value updates

Comment: codesandbox i linked seems to work when focused. If not working the not sure what the issue could be

Comment: Works now. Thanks Max

Comment: no problem brotha

Comment: imposible that this work
```
state.value = { ...state, [name]: value };
```
because you are spreading the reference no the actual value.
should be
state.value = {...state.value, [name]: value}